# In Robots.txt, how do I disallow all pages except for the index page?

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

I want google to index my index page, but do not index any other pages.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So far I have this.  However...when I do this, Google does not index my index page.  When I search my name in Google, all it shows is "www.mydomain.com" as the first result with no description.

Instead, I want Google to index my main index page, WITH the meta description tag, too.

Answer (score 8):

For Google, in particular, the following rules will do the trick:

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

For details, see [Google's documentation of their supported robots.txt syntax](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt).  However, note that the middle line is non-standard for two reasons: first, it's an `Allow` directive (the [basic robots.txt standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) only supports `Disallow`) and second, it uses the non-standard end-of-URL anchor `$`.  That said, several other major search engines, [including Bing](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2008/06/03/robots-exclusion-protocol-joining-together-to-provide-better-documentation.aspx), do support more or less the same syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Google and other search engines support the `Allow:` statement now in addition to `Disallow:`... though they may behave differently on different search engine spiders, and may not be supported or enforced by other types of site scrapers.

Documentation [here](http://blog.semetrical.com/googles-secret-approach-to-robots-txt/)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to disallow Google your pages?

Anyway yo do this you could do:

```
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.html
```

Comment: That won't match the usual root which is '/'

Answer (score 0):

I use like this:

```
User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /index.html
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /index.html
Disallow: /
```